# Commiting transaction within test with Spring test

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

I am testing my repository for update operation

```
@Test

    public void updateStatusByEmailWithEmailCustomer()
    {
        customerQuickRegisterRepository.save(standardEmailCustomer());

        assertEquals(CUST_STATUS_EMAIL,customerQuickRegisterRepository.findByEmail(CUST_EMAIL).getStatus());

        customerQuickRegisterRepository.updateStatusByEmail(CUST_EMAIL,STATUS_EMAIL_VERFIED ); 

        assertEquals(STATUS_EMAIL_VERFIED,customerQuickRegisterRepository.findByEmail(CUST_EMAIL).getStatus());
    }
```

In the test case i saving my entity with default status and after that i am changing it to other using updateStatusByEmail(CUST_EMAIL,STATUS_EMAIL_VERFIED ) but still  next assert statement is failing, this is due to fact that the updates during the test execution are commited after completion of test....Is there any way that I can commit my changes within the test?

Comment: Are you using hibernate?

Comment: yes..hibernate with spring data jpa on top of it.

Comment: Is the test running in a transaction?

Comment: yes...it is running in transaction

Comment: have you thought to transaction propagation REQUIRES_NEW? you could encapsulate your method in another annotated by @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) [LINK](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely get by with *flushing* the underlying Hibernate `Session`, as this will push your changes to the underlying tables in the database (within the current test-managed transaction).

Search for "false positives" in the [testing chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-annotation-demo) of the Spring reference manual for details.

Basically, you will want to call `flush()` on the **current** Hibernate `Session` after your *update* call and before the corresponding assertion.

If that does not solve your problem, with Spring Framework 4.1, you can use the new `TestTransaction` API for [programmatic transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-programmatic-tx-mgt) within tests.

Regards,

Sam (lead of the `spring-test` module)